# How to define a fix value to a variable?

Tags: c#

Title of my question is quite different from my question. I am sorry for that because i don't know what should be title for this question.

Suppose i have one class let's say "ClassA"

```
Class ClassA
{

   int x=5;
   int y=6;
   int z=7;
   static public int sum(int a,int b)
   {
      return (a+b);
   }

}
```

now i need some logic by which i can use sum() like following in another class

```
int c = ClassA.sum(x,y);
int d = ClassA.sum(x,z);
```

here i don't need to declare "x","y" and "z" variable. It must be a consider a value that is defined in ClassA.

My question can be silly but just help me.

What should i do ????

Answer (score 0):

You can declare x, y, and z as `const`:

```
class ClassA
{

   public const int x=5;
   public const int y=6;
   public const int z=7;
   static public int sum(int a,int b)
   {
      return (a+b);
   }
}
```

Then do:

```
int c = ClassA.sum(ClassA.x,ClassA.y);
```

Comment: Is there any other than using constant. (like enumerable or anything else)

Comment: You could declare them static as well if they are mutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance of an object to a static method, it can invoke instance members on that object.

```
class ClassA
{

   int x=5;
   int y=6;
   int z=7;
   static public int sum(ClassA obj)
   {
      return (obj.x+ obj.y);
   }
}
```

In other class create instance of class ClassA and pass this object to static method

```
ClassA objA = new ClassA();
int c = ClassA.sum(objA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following code fits your requirement.

Create an enum as:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    x,y,z
}
```

The classA code will be:

```
class ClassA
{
    static int x = 5;
    static int y = 6;
    static int z = 7;

    static public int sum(MyEnum enum1, MyEnum enum2)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        switch (enum1)
        {
            case MyEnum.x:
                a = x;
                break;
            case MyEnum.y:
                a = y;
                break;
            case MyEnum.z:
                a = z;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        switch (enum2)
        {
            case MyEnum.x:
                b = x;
                break;
            case MyEnum.y:
                b = y;
                break;
            case MyEnum.z:
                b = z;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return (a + b);
    }
}
```

I have set x,y,z as static because your method is static and you cannot access instance members in static method. Or you can replace `static` with `const` while declaring variable x,y,z.

Hope this helps.